# Using VBA to create a CSV from an Excel sheet, ignoring semicolons

Tags: excel, vba, csv

I found code somewhere, and tuned to suit my needs.

Some fields have semicolons, and when I open a freshly generated CSV file in Excel, anything after a semicolon is automatically placed in a new column. That's even before I transform the data. I tried wrapping the semicolons in double quotes, single quotes, quadruple quotes.

```vb
Sub CSV_contact()

    Dim myCSVFileName As String
    Dim myWB As Workbook
    Dim rngToSave As Range
    Dim fNum As Integer
    Dim csvVal As String
    Dim lastrow As Long

    With Sheets("Contactpersonen").UsedRange
        lastrow = .Rows(.Rows.Count).Row
    End With

    Set myWB = ThisWorkbook
    myCSVFileName = Sheets("Instellingen").Range("B4").Value & "\" & "CSV_contactpersonen" & VBA.Format(VBA.Now, "dd-MMM-yyyy hh-mm") & ".csv"
    csvVal = ""
    fNum = FreeFile
    Set rngToSave = Range("A10:O" & lastrow)

    Open myCSVFileName For Output As #fNum

    For i = 1 To rngToSave.Rows.Count
        For j = 1 To rngToSave.Columns.Count
            csvVal = csvVal & Chr(34) & Replace(rngToSave(i, j).Value, ";", Chr(34) & Chr(34) & ";" & Chr(34) & Chr(34)) & Chr(34) & ","
            Debug.Print csvVal
        Next
        Print #fNum, Left(csvVal, Len(csvVal) - 2)
        csvVal = ""
    Next

    Close #fNum
End Sub
```

When I use debug print, this is what a typical line looks like:

```
"normal string 1","normal string 2","string containing"";"" somewhere"";"" in the middle","","","","another normal string after some empty columns",
```

Mind that this is one of the things I tried, the first thing I tried created lines where the semicolon strings looked like this:

```
"string containing; somewhere; in the middle"
```

Is there an escape character, like / or *, I can put in front of it?

I read about having to write my own CSV parser, but that's beyond my skill level.

My client uses European Excel, so the comma is the standard decimal delimiter. Maybe the solution would be to (temporarily) set the delimiter to a point? I prefer it to be temporary as my client is an accountant and values correct layout.

Comment: When I save my file as a csv using Excels `SaveAs` feature, I don't have any problems with cells containing commas, colons, or semi-colons. Have you tried saving your file as CSV directly or using `Workbook.SaveAs`?

Comment: That's my solution if all else fails; there's some queries and some other shenanigans going on in the first couple of rows, and for cleanliness' sake I wanted to make a macro that would convert a set range to CSV, instead of they entire sheet.

Comment: You could have the macro copy that data into a new workbook which then gets turned into the CSV.

Comment: That is exactly the type of outside-the-box thing I was looking for. Sometimes you bite down into a specific problem so hard you can't see anything else

Comment: Excel is very finicky when it comes to **open**ing a csv file. I believe you can get consistent and correct results by **import**ing the file. When you do that, you can set all the criteria properly that are not contained within a CSV file (eg: encoding, separator, date order, culture, etc).  You can do this using either the legacy wizard, or, more flexibly, Power Query (part of Excel since 2010).

Comment: You need to quote the whole cell value to escape something that might be a separator.  Don’t just quote the one character.